# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeeaa26f48)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have no clue what this error means

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeeaa26f48)
```

which means I have no clue how to fix my code. Please help me. Here is my code below if you need it. If you need more code ask me please. I hope you guys can help me. Edit: I included all of my code. I hope you guys can use it and sorry for not defining the variables that were necessary for this question. Again I hope you guys can solve this.

```
var score = 0
var randomAmountOfTime = Double(arc4random_uniform(5) + 2)
var randomAmountOfTime2 = Double(arc4random_uniform(5) + 2)
var randomAmountOfTime3 = Double(arc4random_uniform(5) + 2)
var randomAmountOfTime4 = Double(arc4random_uniform(5) + 2)
var randomAmountOfTime5 = Double(arc4random_uniform(5) + 2)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if X != nil {
        X.text = ""
    }
    if Puppy5 != nil {
        Puppy5.isHidden = true
    }
    if Puppy4 != nil {
        Puppy4.isHidden = true
    }
    if Puppy3 != nil {
        Puppy3.isHidden = true
    }
    if Puppy2 != nil {
        Puppy2.isHidden = true
    }
    if Puppy1 != nil {
        Puppy1.isHidden = true
    }
    score = 0
    if Score != nil {
        Score.text = "Score - \(score)"
    }
    loadingProcess()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBOutlet var Score: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var X: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Puppy5: UIButton!
@IBAction func puppy5(_ sender: Any) {
    Puppy5.isHidden = true
    score += 1
    Score.text = "Score - \(score)"

}
@IBOutlet var Puppy4: UIButton!
@IBAction func puppy4(_ sender: Any) {
    Puppy4.isHidden = true
    score += 1
    Score.text = "Score - \(score)"

}
@IBOutlet var Puppy3: UIButton!
@IBAction func puppy3(_ sender: Any) {
    Puppy3.isHidden = true
    score += 1
    Score.text = "Score - \(score)"

}
@IBOutlet var Puppy2: UIButton!
@IBAction func puppy2(_ sender: Any) {
    Puppy2.isHidden = true
    score += 1
    Score.text = "Score - \(score)"
}
@IBOutlet var Puppy1: UIButton!
@IBAction func puppy1(_ sender: Any) {
    Puppy1.isHidden = true
    score += 1
    Score.text = "Score - \(score)"

}
func loadingProcess() {
    if self.Puppy1 != nil && self.Puppy1.isHidden == true {
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + randomAmountOfTime
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            self.Puppy1.isHidden = false
            self.loadingProcess()
        }
    } else if self.Puppy1 != nil && self.Puppy1.isHidden == false {
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 3
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            self.Puppy1.isHidden = true
            if self.X.text == "X" {
                self.X.text = "X X"
            } else if self.X.text == "" {
                self.X.text = "X"
            } else if self.X.text == "X X" {
                self.X.text = "X X X"
            }
        }
    }
    self.loadingProcess()
}
```

Comment: You might help us if you posted more code. What's `Puppy1`? What's 'X'? What's with the recursive calls to `loadingProcess()`? In general, what are you trying to do with this code? EDIT: More questions. What line of code is generating the error? What is calling `loadingProcess()`, and is it in an override of something the OS does? LAST EDIT: The idea is we need to duplicate the issue. From appearances your code builds, right? So we need more details - yes, code and explanation of what you are doing - to actually be of help. Thanks!

Comment: To add to @dfd what is `randomAmountOfTime`? Always explain what the code should be doing and what the expected result should be.

Comment: Oh sorry I'll make sure to add the definitions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're calling `self.loadingProcess()` recursively without any condition. This infinite loop is certainly causing the crash.

Comment: Btw, you can check the debug navigator (on the left side navigator) to see how many times this method is called. It may be a lot

Comment: Oh it's suppose to do that because I did it to repeat.

Comment: calling recursively a method this way always leads to a crash. I'm not sure I understand your goal with this last line of code

Comment: Thanks for telling me. Do you any ideas on how I could repeat

Comment: If you want to repeat periodically you can use a timer. timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInteral, target: self, selector: #selector(self.loadingProcess), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)